# Return an index that is between two values in two different lists

Tags: python

So I need to set a variable to an index of a list if it is higher than the value from the first list but lower than the value from a second list. I have flowDir as a value from 0 to 360. I am trying to set Direction variable to the right index

```
new_array1 = [22.5, 67.5, 112.5, 157.5, 202.5, 247.5, 292.5, 337.5]
new_array2 = [67.5, 112.5, 157.5, 202.5, 247.5,292.5, 337.5, 22.5]

for n in range(8):
    array1 = new_array1[n]
    array2 = new_array2[n]
    if flowDir > array1 and  flowDir < array2:
        Direction = n
```

Comment: What do you mean "set to right index"?  Wouldn't the indexes of the left and right array be the same.

Comment: Could you show an example or two of the expected input/output? What would be the desired `Direction` if `flowDir` was `100`? `210`?

Comment: If flowDir is 100, I want Direction to be array1[1] (second index) of the list. If flowDir is 210, Direction = array1[4]. Thanks for the response. In this code n represents grid cell's eight neighbors in a 3 by 3 .moving window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the angles are in order, you can use `bisect.bisect_left()`:

```
import bisect

angles = [22.5, 67.5, 112.5, 157.5, 202.5, 247.5, 292.5, 337.5]
flow_dir = 100
print(bisect.bisect_left(angles, flow_dir ) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html#numpy.digitize) also uses binary search

```
import numpy as np


bins = [22.5, 67.5, 112.5, 157.5, 202.5, 247.5, 292.5, 337.5]

flow_dir = 100

int(np.digitize(flow_dir, bins)) - 1

Out[21]: 1
```

and you can give it a list(or array) of dirs

```
flow_dirs = [100, 210, 50, 300]

np.digitize(flow_dirs, bins) - 1

Out[23]: array([1, 4, 0, 6], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: @Simon Gudim please check one answer as accepted - as you gain more reputaiton points you will also be able to upvote answers